# How can I fix the way my site shows up on screens of different sizes and resolutions?

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design, liquid-layout

You can see my site at http://www.taramenconi.byethost11.com/ . I designed it for 1024 x 768. I've also notices that on some screens, it just looks widely stretched... I purposely created the backgrounds to fill larger browsers but I want the content area to stay the same size. How can I fix that?

Here's my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MonaKoRegular';
src: url('monako-webfont.eot');
src: url('monako-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('monako-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('monako-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('monako-webfont.svg#MonaKoRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'StMarieThin';
    src: url('stmarie-thin-webfont.eot');
    src: url('stmarie-thin-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('stmarie-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('stmarie-thin-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('stmarie-thin-webfont.svg#StMarieThin') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
body {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
p {
    font-family: StMarieThin;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #666;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.section {
    float: left;
    width: 1920px;
    top: -10px;
    height: 1080px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.content {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(contentbox.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 653px;
    width: 870px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 190px;
    width: 730px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
}
.logo img a {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
}
.body {
    height: 353px;
    width: 630px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 90px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.body img{
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}
#tagline_home {
    color: #F00;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#home_scrollbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 267px;
    height: 330px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#about_scrollbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 267px;
    height: 330px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#menu_scrollbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 267px;
    height: 330px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#daily_scrollbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 267px;
    height: 330px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#catering_scrollbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 267px;
    height: 330px;
    width: 630px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.navigation {
    height: 190px;
    width: 180px;
    padding-left: 140px;
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    background-image: url(navdivider.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 140%;
}
.navigation ul {
    font-family: MonaKoRegular;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 150%;
}
.navigation ul li a {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.navigation ul li a:current {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #f00;    
}
#about_scrollbox ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
h2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 20px;
}
#home {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(home.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#about {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(About.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#menu {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(DailySpecials.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#daily {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(Menu.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#catering {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(Catering.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    padding: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    height:30px;
    display: block;
    background-color:transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color:#F00;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
.nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Your website seems fine on my screen. My display is 1680 x 1050.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fixed width div into which all your content would go, and set the left and right margins of a containing div to `auto`. That should keep your fixed width div in the middle of the browser window.

Or, you could use `media queries` to create a number of different stylesheets to suit different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

Create a "wrapper" fixed witdh div with `margin-right:auto` and `margin-left:auto` wrapping all the elements.

If you want a fluid design you must use media-queries: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/